# App crashing on Samsung Tab 4

Tags: android, performance, crash, android-4.4-kitkat, samsung-mobile

My application is working fine on all the devices except the one Samsung galaxy Tab 4 with android 4.4.2 version. It is keep on crashing for with in two minutes on any screen. While checking this my app taking around 200 Mb in cached background process. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have any logs?

Comment: How can WE solve it without any details? We don't even know what your app is doing...Please be more specific, include relevant code, logcat etc.

Comment: I have implemented two webserivces and google map in the app. Also i have schedule a web service for every minute with timer task.